# How to overstep maxsize in python?

Tags: python, arrays, memory-management, max-size

It is said from http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html that maxsize is [...]  the maximum size [...] ! And guess what ? I need to overstep it !

On my 64 bits system, it comes that maxsize = 2**63-1 = 9223372036854775807

If an array is maxsized, is a N-dimensional array N-maxsized ?

Because in python an N-dimensionnal array is an array into an array, I guess that code is valuable in order to overstep the maxsize limit ?

Understoud that I need memory ...

```
array=[]
i,j=0
while j<(2**63-1):
   while i<(2**63-1):
      array[j].append(1)
      i=i+1
j=j+1
```

Comment: You'll likely be long dead by the time that loop finishes, so does it really matter? Not to mention, nobody's ever built a machine with that much memory yet...

Comment: Eric Schmidt, the CEO of Google, [...], estimated the size at roughly 5 million terabytes of data. Yes, we have memory ...

Comment: 5 million terrabytes is *only* 5x10^20 bytes. 2^63*2^63 = 2^126 ~= 8.5x10^37. Not even close - you'd need on the order of 10^17 Googles or something like 15 million Googles per person on the planet, and that's only if each datum is one byte and there's no overhead for heap management, pointers, etc...

Comment: I REALLY understand that I need a "1-atom per bit" memory and the whole universe of atoms to TRY to approach 2**256 ... :) REALLY ... I just want to understand how maxsize of an object could be overstepped. Object of objects could in fact ... And if i throw an infinity of memory in a box, this box could serve the code with an infinity of energy ... Is my code correct ? Yes, I think. Is a computer ready to run, I gues : NO :)=

Comment: Have you ever wrote a code that will never end ?

Comment: The point is, if you think you need code like this, as you seem to claim, then you are very obviously doing something very wrong and need to rethink your design, or you are taking the "path of least resistance" and writing what is very simple code, but is completely untenable from an efficiency standpoint - a naive nested loop is sometimes the easiest way to think about a problem, but as the problem size grows, it quickly becomes the least feasible solution...

Comment: I just need to overstep the maxsize limitation in python ... is my code right in order to do this ? I agree, this code is the least I would launch on any box ... And if I need one day to parse any 2**63 array, I will not use python, but VHDL with a very fast memory such as metallic nanocrystals ...

Comment: it is said that i purge any parsed memory at least before filling the whole memory ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugs and legacy cruft non withstanding, `maxsize` is (approximately) the largest size a container<sup>1</sup> can be. You cannot have a list that large even on a 64 bit system, for simple reasons of address space limitations (and some choices in the implementation, but those are a consequence of the aforementioned limit). You can't even store 2^63-1 *bytes* on your computer (not even on the hard disk!), much less 2^63-1 fully blown Python objects.

You have no idea how much memory your example code needs that. Your CPU can't even address a tiny fraction of the memory needed for that. Not even your whole hard disk would be able to hold a significant fraction. You'd need 8 million hard disks of 1 TiB capacity *each* to store 2^63-1 *bytes*, and 8 times that for equally many `1`s. That exceeds even the alleged capacity of the NSA's Utah data center by far. And that's 2^63-1, *not* 2^63 * 2^63 = 2^126. The latter figure is ridiculous to think of in physical terms. This is in the order of magnitude that cannot be enumerated or brute forced and can be randomly sampled without getting duplicates.

**If** that physical limit didn't exist, or if an artificial limit on list size existed that was smaller than the actual physical limit, you could indeed use a list within a list to sidestep the problem. This is unlikely to be an actual problem in practice though. The *minimum* limit on container size is around 2 billion.

<sup>1</sup> Under the assumption that each element of a container physically exists in RAM, not moved to the disk or calculated on demand or anything.

Comment: Ok, I understand well the physical limit. You replied that a list within a list sidestep the problem. So I can now launch my program and go for a sleep :)

Comment: @mat.viguier You don't *appear* to understand. A list within a list sidesteps sys.maxsize, it does not change that your program will eat all memory your computer could possibly have (RAM and page file) and crash due to being out of memory before even getting close to any limit imposed by Python (e.g. sys.maxsize).

Comment: It was a joke Delnan, i do not want to sleep for a billion year even if I have a lot of memory :)

Comment: I mean I'm aware of h ≈ 4,1343359×10-15 eV⋅s ... and I sware I understand well :) I guess that code will not be ran at all :)